# select first record into field1 and other records into field2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a **table1** with id's. Another **table2** with two fields; **master**, and **child**.

I need to select the **first Id** from **table1** as **master** in **table2**, and the **other id**s as **child** in **table2**.

[image: 1]
I tried this:

```
Dim rs as recordset
Dim strSql as String  

strSql = "Select top 1 Id FROM table1"           
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
rs.MoveFirst
strSql = "INSERT INTO table2 (child) SELECT table1.Id FROM table1 WHERE Id <> " & rs.Fields(0).Value
DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
strSql = "UPDATE table2 SET master = " & rs.Fields(0).Value & " WHERE master is null"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSql 
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

But since I have to do the same thing for different tables many times in the code, I'd rather do this if possible with one query. If possible without a subquery as well.

Comment: How will you define `first Id` in `table1`

Comment: @VR46, the lowest id. or the first.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Use VBA. DMin() to lookup the min. id, then an INSERT with the id + all other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that supposing that your ID is a numeric column

```
SELECT Table2.id, Table2.child
FROM (SELECT MIN(id) AS master FROM Table1) AS Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
     ON Table1.master = Table2.id
```

I don't see a way to do it without a subquery.

Comment: In MSACCESS you can create a table with the min(id) and you can join it with the Table2, as showed above.